# ¿Como implentar un codigo a una GUI con Tkinter o cualquiers libreria para GUI's?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Mi nombre es Alonso. Soy nuevo programando y desarrollando apliciones con GUI en python, la meta que quiero realizar es meter mi programa en una GUI nomas que diga que esta activo. He buscado en forums y leyendo libros pero no me queda muy claro el manejo del mainloop o como implementarlo dentro del mismo.

El programa realizado funciona de esta manera. Lee los datos que manda un modulo serial y los va registrando en una archivo TXT, cuando termina la codicion de registro los archivos los convierte a CSV, hace un formato con diseño en excel leyendo los datos que hay en los archivos CSV y por ultimo lo manda imprimir a una impresora local. Los datos se borran y vuelve a empezar el proceso.

Intente usar el mismo loop que tiene Tkinter pero no me respondio como esperaba. Pero no me funcino como un While True.

Intente hacerlos por seperados primero la venta y despues el codigo de registro pero lo que realizaba era que la ventana se abria primero y despues el registro.

Mi pregunta es ¿Cual es la manera de poder implentar el codigo dentro del loop del GUI?

Muchas gracias por su tiempo, espero que tengan un excelente dia.
NOTA. los '###' Direccion en donde estan guardados los archivos guardados

Un ejemplo a mano de lo que quiero lograr a implentar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
if __name__=='__main__':
  com_serial=serial.Serial("COM6",19200)

  if com_serial.isOpen():
     print('PUERTO SERIE ABIERTO')
     print('Modo produccion')
     print('Estado del puerto serial: ',com_serial.isOpen())
     print('Conexion: ',com_serial.name)
     
     print('\n#############\n')

  else:
     print('puerto serie fallo')
   
  try:
     conditonal_count=0
     count_data=0
    
     while True:
         register_data=open('D:\\#######\\Registro_de_datos.txt','a')
         register_parameters=open('D:\\######\\Parametros_iniciales.txt','a')
         waiting_data=com_serial.inWaiting()

         if waiting_data>0:
            com_serial.timeout=1
            lector_data=com_serial.readline()
            conditonal_count+=1
            print(lector_data)  

            if conditonal_count<=2:
                register_parameters.write(lector_data.decode('utf-8'))
                register_parameters.write('\n') 

            if conditonal_count>2:
                register_parameters.close()
                csv_parameters()
                #Cuanto producto va a corree
                parameters_csv_product=reader_csv.read_csv('D:\\#####\\Parametros_iniciales.csv').fillna('')
                parameters_csv_product_int=int(parameters_csv_product.loc[0,'Production'])

                #Condiciones
                close_register_data=parameters_csv_product_int+1
                clear_files=parameters_csv_product_int+3
                count_data+=1
                

                if count_data==2:
                #Hora que inicia la produccion 
                    localtime_pc_in=time.localtime(time.time())
                    check_in_hour=localtime_pc_in[3]
                    check_in_min=localtime_pc_in[4]
                    check_in_sec=localtime_pc_in[5]
                    check_in='{0}:{1}:{2}'.format(check_in_hour,check_in_min,check_in_sec)
                    print('Hora de inicio: ',check_in)

                #Registro de datos 
                if count_data<=close_register_data:
                    register_data.write(lector_data.decode('utf-8'))
                    register_data.write('\n')

                if count_data==close_register_data:
                    #Hora que termina 
                    localtime_pc_out=time.localtime(time.time())
                    check_out_hour=localtime_pc_out[3]
                    check_out_min=localtime_pc_out[4]
                    check_out_sec=localtime_pc_out[5]
                    check_out='{0}:{1}:{2}'.format(check_out_hour,check_out_min,check_out_sec)
                    print('hora de terminacion: ',check_out)
                    count_data+=1
                                        
                if count_data>close_register_data:
                    register_data.close()
                    csv_data()
                    to_complete='Completa'
                    convert_to_excel=1
            
                    if convert_to_excel==1:
                    #Comparacion de hora 
                        excel_format(check_in,check_out,to_complete)
                        metada_data=reader_csv.read_csv("D:\\#####\\Registro_de_datos.csv")
                        format_size=len(metada_data)
                        if format_size<=20: 
                            time_stop=5
                            print_now=1
                        elif format_size>20 or format_size<=100:
                            time_stop=7
                            print_now=1
                        elif format_size>100 or format_size<=1000000000:
                            time_stop=10
                            print_now=1
                    
                        if print_now==1:
                            print_data()
                            print(time_stop)
                            time.sleep(time_stop)
                            count_data+=1
                                    
                            if count_data==clear_files:
                                rename_database()
                                print('Listo para siguiente ronda')    
                                os.remove('D:\\#####\\Parametros_iniciales.txt')
                                os.remove('D:\#####\\Registro_de_datos.txt')
                                os.remove('D:\\#####\\Parametros_iniciales.csv')            
                                os.remove('D:\\#####\\Registro_de_datos.csv')
                                count_data=0
                                print_now=0
                                conditonal_count=0
                                convert_to_excel=0

            if lector_data==b'Detener':
                register_data.close()
                localtime_pc_out=time.localtime(time.time())
                check_out_hour=localtime_pc_out[3]
                check_out_min=localtime_pc_out[4]
                check_out_sec=localtime_pc_out[5]
                check_out='{0}:{1}:{2}'.format(check_out_hour,check_out_min,check_out_sec)
                print('hora de terminacion: ',check_out)
                to_complete='Incompleto'

                folder_data=open("D:\\#####\\Registro_de_datos.txt","r")
                lines_data=folder_data.readlines()
                folder_data.close()
                folder_data=open("D:\\#####\\Registro_de_datos.txt","w")

                for line_data in lines_data:
                    if line_data!="Detener"+"\n": 
                        folder_data.write(line_data)
                folder_data.close()
                csv_data()
                convert_to_excel=1

                if convert_to_excel==1:
                    #Comparacion de hora 
                    excel_format(check_in,check_out,to_complete)
                    metada_data=reader_csv.read_csv("D:\\P#####\\Registro_de_datos.csv")
                    format_size=len(metada_data)
                    if format_size<=20: 
                        time_stop=5
                        print_now=1
                    elif format_size>20 or format_size<=100:
                        time_stop=7
                        print_now=1
                    elif format_size>100 :
                        time_stop=10
                        print_now=1

                    if print_now==1:
                        print_data()
                        time.sleep(time_stop)
                        rename_database()
                        count_data=clear_files

                        if count_data==clear_files:
                                print('Listo para siguiente ronda')    
                                os.remove('D:\\#####\\Parametros_iniciales.txt')
                                os.remove('D:\\#####\\Registro_de_datos.txt')
                                os.remove('D:\\#####\\Parametros_iniciales.csv')            
                                os.remove('D:\\#####\\Registro_de_datos.csv')
                                count_data=0
                                print_now=0
                                conditonal_count=0
                                convert_to_excel=0
          
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Puerto serie cerrado')
    register_parameters.close()
    register_data.close()
    
    if com_serial!=None:      
        com_serial.close()
        os.remove('D:\\#####\\Parametros_iniciales.txt')
        os.remove('D:\\#####\\Registro_de_datos.txt')
        os.remove('D:\\#####\\Parametros_iniciales.csv')            
        os.remove('D:\\#####\\Registro_de_datos.csv')
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] y modifica tu pregunta para que 1. no solicite recursos externos (tutoriales, etc), 2. no pregunte por "la mejor forma de", ya que estos tipos de preguntas (basadas en opiniones, solicitando recursos externos) terminan [cerradas](/help/closed-questions).

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que debe mostrar la GUI? ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo aunque sea dibujado "a mano" para entender cómo se relaciona esa GUI con el código que proporcionas?

Comment: @abulafia es una GUI sencilla la que trato de implentar nomas que diga si es verdadero o falso si esta en registro de datos, el fin de implentar el GUI es que no puedan moverle o modificar el programa

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues un [example] para que sea más fácil ayudarte

Comment: ¿Cuál es la condición que le permite salir del bucle infinito? No veo que contenga ningún break, por lo que parece que la única forma de salir es cuando se produce la excepción `KeyboardInterrupt` ¿Es el puerto serie el que produce esa excepción, o es el usuario pulsando Ctrl+C en el teclado? Porque si es lo segundo, sería necesario inventar otro mecanismo para que funcione dentro de Tkinter

Comment: @abulafia Funciona en el Ctrl+C para poder para cortar el bucle infinito, si fuera el primero caso, como se podria implentar, voy a buscar la manera de poder implentar el break

Comment: Se supone que en el bucle, cuando recibes datos del puerto serie, tiene que haber algún dato que indique que ya no hay más. Parece que en tu caso es la cadena "Detener". Cuando detectas esa cadena, haces lo que tengas que hacer con tu csv y después pones `break`. Eso hará que salga del bucle y no necesitas entonces matarlo con Ctrl+C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo comenzaría por implementar todo ese código que tienes escrito en un par de funciones. La primera que repita el bucle de recepción de datos hasta detectar el final de los mismos (sería tu bucle `while True`, pero con un `break` cuando se detecte esa condición). La segunda que haga lo que necesites una vez se han terminado los datos del puerto serie (escribir en disco, crear csv o lo que sea).

La idea es que con Tk puedas crear una interfaz de usuario que pueda lanzar en un hilo aparte a otra función que se ocupe de llamar a las dos anteriores por orden. Primero a la que recibe los datos, hasta que ésta retorne, y después a la que los vuelca a excel. De este modo esta función puede ir actualizando la interfaz de usuario con mensajes del estado en que se halla ("recibiendo datos", "escribiendo en disco", ...)

Te voy a suministrar un ejemplo de cómo podría ser este programa Tk, pero para que se pueda probar y demostrar su funcionamiento he eliminado todo el código que lee del puerto serie y escribe en discos, y lo he reemplazado por un mero bucle que pierde el tiempo (5 segundos para simular la recepción de datos y otros 3 segundos para simular el volcado de la excel).

Además he añadido un botón para que, hasta que no se pulse, no comience ninguna operación con el puerto serie.

El código sería el siguiente:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button, Frame, Label
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
import threading
import time

def recibir_datos():
    # Aquí iría tu while True, pero con una condición
    # que le haga terminar con un break
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)

def volcar_a_csv():
    # Aquí iría el código que vuelca los datos a csv
    for i in range(3):
        time.sleep(1)

def funcion_principal(progress: Progressbar, texto1: Label, texto2: Label):
    """Esta función se ocupa de llamar en orden a las dos anteriores
    pero también actualiza la interfaz de usuario con los mensajes
    apropiados y arranca y detiene la barra de progreso"""
    progress.start()

    texto1.config(text="CONECTADO")
    texto2.config(text="Buffer de datos en registro")
    recibir_datos()

    texto1.config(text="DESCONECTADO")
    texto2.config(text="Volcando a CSV")
    volcar_a_csv()

    progress.destroy()
    texto1.config(text="")
    texto2.config(text="Terminado")

class GUI(Frame):
    """Interfaz gráfica de usuario"""
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        # Comienza teniendo tan solo un botón que al pulsarse lanza
        # la función "empezar"
        self.go_Button=Button(self.parent,text="Empezar",command=self.empezar)
        self.go_Button.place(x=100, y=50, anchor="center")

    def empezar(self):
        # Esta función elimina el botón "empezar" para que no se pueda
        # pulsar otra vez, y crea los elementos de la interfaz donde
        # ir actualizando el estado
        self.go_Button.destroy()
        progress=Progressbar(self.parent,mode='indeterminate',length=200)
        progress.place(x=100, y=90, anchor="center")

        texto1 = Label(self.parent)
        texto1.place(x=100, y=20, anchor="center")

        texto2 = Label(self.parent)
        texto2.place(x=100, y=40, anchor="center")

        # Finalmente lanza en un hilo aparte la función principal
        # y le pasa como parámetros los elementos de la interfaz para
        # que pueda actualizarlos
        self.t=threading.Thread(target=funcion_principal, args=(progress, texto1, texto2))
        self.t.daemon=True
        self.t.start()
        print("Hilo lanzado")

# Crear ventena principal, crear en ella la GUI y arrancarla
main_window = tk.Tk()
main_window.geometry("200x100")
g = GUI(main_window)
main_window.mainloop()
```

Demo de funcionamiento:

[image: Video demo]